# How to start with sencha touch 2.0 chart beta?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-charts

I need to know how i can make a column chart with the sencha touch chart 2.0, the documentation is the same as 1.0 and i know that chart 1 and 2 are incompatible.

How i can make a view with a chart?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the touch charts 2 beta is available to download, you can start it from the build-in examples and demos.

[Touch Chart beta 2](http://cdn.sencha.io/touch-charts-2.0.0-beta.zip)